# PhpBB - Where Is The PHP File To Display overall_footer.html?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

PhpBB - Where Is The PHP File To Display overall_footer.html?

I have checked lots of php file, but still can't find it.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear. If you are looking for where overall_footer.html is called from, it is included from other template files, not called directly.

Whenever you view a page, it shows one template file. For forum index its index_body.html for topics list its viewforum_body.html, for topic its viewtopic_body.html and so on. Each of those files starts with this line:

```
<!-- INCLUDE overall_header.html -->
```

and ends with this line:

```
<!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html -->
```

That's where overall_footer.html is included from.

If you were looking for location of compiled overall_footer.html (php version of it), its located in directory cache and file name for prosilver's version is tpl_prosilver_overall_footer.html.php. You should never edit that file, if you want to add something, edit overall_footer.html template instead.

Comment: And to add to that, if you do edit the template file, don't forget to refresh the template in the ACP.

Answer (score 0):

The file "overall_footer.html" is not called from any PHP file directly. Instead it is included inside of other template files, which are called by various PHP files. Here is a list of all templates that include this file:

```
<pre>
\adm\style\acp_attachments.html (1 hits)
    Line 376: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_ban.html (1 hits)
    Line 124: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_bbcodes.html (1 hits)
    Line 124: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_board.html (1 hits)
    Line 49: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_bots.html (1 hits)
    Line 102: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_captcha.html (1 hits)
    Line 71: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_database.html (1 hits)
    Line 98: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_disallow.html (1 hits)
    Line 45: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_email.html (1 hits)
    Line 58: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_forums.html (1 hits)
    Line 505: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_forums_copy_perm.html (1 hits)
    Line 22: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_groups.html (1 hits)
    Line 358: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_icons.html (1 hits)
    Line 268: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_inactive.html (1 hits)
    Line 77: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_jabber.html (1 hits)
    Line 65: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_language.html (1 hits)
    Line 255: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_logs.html (1 hits)
    Line 93: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_main.html (1 hits)
    Line 255: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_modules.html (1 hits)
    Line 212: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_permissions.html (1 hits)
    Line 357: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_permission_roles.html (1 hits)
    Line 202: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_php_info.html (1 hits)
    Line 13: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_profile.html (1 hits)
    Line 236: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_prune_forums.html (1 hits)
    Line 108: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_prune_users.html (1 hits)
    Line 59: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_ranks.html (1 hits)
    Line 98: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_reasons.html (1 hits)
    Line 127: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_search.html (1 hits)
    Line 157: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_send_statistics.html (1 hits)
    Line 71: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_styles.html (1 hits)
    Line 536: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_update.html (1 hits)
    Line 52: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_users.html (1 hits)
    Line 234: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\acp_words.html (1 hits)
    Line 77: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\captcha_gd_acp.html (1 hits)
    Line 74: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\captcha_qa_acp.html (1 hits)
    Line 92: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\captcha_recaptcha_acp.html (1 hits)
    Line 50: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\confirm_bbcode.html (1 hits)
    Line 22: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\confirm_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 20: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\confirm_body_prune.html (1 hits)
    Line 30: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\message_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 8: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\adm\style\permission_forum_copy.html (1 hits)
    Line 40: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\confirm_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 20: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\faq_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 52: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\index_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 48: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\login_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 70: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\login_forum.html (1 hits)
    Line 36: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\mcp_approve.html (1 hits)
    Line 53: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\mcp_footer.html (1 hits)
    Line 9: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\mcp_move.html (1 hits)
    Line 36: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\memberlist_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 183:   &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\memberlist_email.html (1 hits)
    Line 65: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\memberlist_leaders.html (1 hits)
    Line 76: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\memberlist_view.html (1 hits)
    Line 116: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\message_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 11: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\posting_layout.html (1 hits)
    Line 90: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\report_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 51: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\search_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 128: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\search_results.html (1 hits)
    Line 160: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\ucp_agreement.html (1 hits)
    Line 73: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\ucp_footer.html (1 hits)
    Line 15: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\ucp_register.html (1 hits)
    Line 113: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\ucp_remind.html (1 hits)
    Line 32: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\ucp_resend.html (1 hits)
    Line 32: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\viewforum_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 219: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\viewonline_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 57: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;
\styles\prosilver\template\viewtopic_body.html (1 hits)
    Line 274: &lt;!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html --&gt;

</pre>
```